# How to execute a function only if there is a delay?

Tags: javascript, events, time, delay

I want to create a loading bar on a page that should appear only if user waits 2 or more seconds on an async request. I have this code:

```
loading: function() {
    $(document).on("tdi:ajax:start", function() {
        $('.loader').addClass("loader--show");
    });

    $(document).on("tdi:ajax:end", function() {
        $('.loader').removeClass("loader--show");
    });
},
```

But right now the loading bar flashes on the screen whenever there is even 1ms long request. If I set a timeout on the addClass, it just delays when the loading bar appears and then it won't disappear because the end event fired in the meantime. So somehow after the start event fires I need to measure if the end event occured and if not, add the loaderClass until the end event fires. Any idea how could I achieve this?

Comment: When the start event fires, set a flag to true, and start a timeout. When the end event fires, set the flag to false. When the timeout fires, check the flag; if it's true, add the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loading: function() {
    let timeoutId; 
    $(document).on("tdi:ajax:start", function() {
        // This will init the delayed execution
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { 
           $('.loader').addClass("loader--show"); 
        }, 2000);
    });

    $(document).on("tdi:ajax:end", function() {
        // This will clear timeout and cancel it execution
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        $('.loader').removeClass("loader--show");
    });
},
```

Comment: You do not even need to test. `clearTimeout(timeoutId);` will not give error on a non-existing timeoutId

Comment: You can move the `timeoutId` inside the outer anonymous function.

Comment: For some reason on very quick ajax actions the `loader--show` class never gets removed and the loader just sits there forever. If I try it on the very long requests, it works. After 2s, the loader appears and then when it is done it disappears. But when the event ends in just a few ms, it just hangs there.

Comment: Can you add logging and see what happens? It seems like timeout not being cleared properly...

Comment: It seems like every time there is an async request, the script loads again so the script runs a couple of times at the same time

Comment: I marked it as an answer because it is a correct answer. There is however a different way to do it. By setting animation-delay on the loader. It shows up with a delay and if the class gets removed before the animation starts it never starts.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to declare a variable in your `loading` function, move the `addClass` portion into a `setTimeout` within your `tdi:ajax:start` event function, and assign the timeoutId generated by `setTimeout` to the previously declared variable. Then, inside your `tdi:ajax:end` event function you can call `clearTimeout` on the timeoutId before you remove the class. This should prevent the class from being re-added after you remove it.